# Echo Difference in Two Times

Tags: php, time

I have a PHP script that collects a timestamp in a database in the HH:MM:SS format. I then have a PHP page that is refreshed every second via AJAX, the goal of which is to produce a script that pulls PHP data every second so I can do things like display a countdown timer. I am trying to display the difference in two times in this format: HH:MM:SS. IE:

```
$currentstampedtime = date("H:i:s", strtotime("now"));
```

Produces:

```
19:29:34
```

(and counts up with my ajax script correctly, appears as a clock.

```
$gametimestamp = date("H:i:s", strtotime($gametime));
```

Produces:

```
19:19:12
```

By pulling the timestamp from my DB, stored in $gametime.

What I am trying to do is get the difference between these two echo'ed out in real time like a countdown timer, assuming the ajax refreshes the page every second like it appears to be doing.

```
$difference = ($currentstampedtime - $gametimestamp);
```

Does nothing. When I echo the var,

```
echo $difference;
```

I get

```
1
```

Nothing I have tried is working. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strtotime("now")` can be `time()` Subtract the timestamps, not the strings. e.g. `strtotime($gametime)` and `time()`. The difference will be in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use php [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object to create your current time and target time. Then, use the [`diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function of the DateTime object to get the difference and format it as "00:00:00".

i.e. :

```
$now = new DateTime();
$target = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', "01:30:00");
$difference = $now->diff($target);
echo $difference->format("%H:%I:%S");
```

Output :

> 00:57:48

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the simplest and most elegant solution thus far. Thank you.

Comment: If I now wanted to take this:
    echo $difference->format("%H:%I:%S");
and create a countdown timer with is using a set time, ie: 30 seconds, how would I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. Do you mean you want to know how many seconds form `$now` to `$target` ?

Comment: Not quite.$target is actually a timestamp in the past, so what is happening is the output is an elapsed time, not a countdown. My objective is to output a timer, which will be the difference between $target (the timestamp) and a time that is 30 seconds in the future from the timestamp.

Comment: Disregard. I cracked it finally. The solution was to add 30 seconds to the timestamp prior to this script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

```
<?php    
    $difference = time()-strtotime($gametime);
    // You can retrieve the difference as time
    echo $currentstampedtime = date("H:i:s", $difference);
?>
```

**UPDATE**

Another solution

```
<?php
    function get_time_difference($time1, $time2) {
        $time1 = strtotime("1980-01-01 $time1");
        $time2 = strtotime("1980-01-01 $time2");
        if ($time2 < $time1) {
            $time2 += 86400;
        }
        return date("H:i:s", strtotime("1980-01-01 00:00:00") + ($time2 - $time1));
    }
    echo get_time_difference("10:25:30", "22:40:59"); // 12:15:29
?>
```