# Formatting error after finding the difference in time with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to find the minutes between two times with php. I have followed the answers I found from other questions on Stack and researched the PHP manual. In my situation, I am getting a DATETIME that is stored in the database and comparing it to NOW. I think my issue lies with a formatting issue.  I will post what I have put together.

```
$order_start = $obj->order_start;   //getting detetime from database query  
$order_start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', $order_start); 
$order_start= $order_start->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'); //format detetime 

$now_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s'); //get now time 


$diff=date_diff($order_time,$now_date);  //get difference

$diff=$diff->format("%i minutes");  //format difference
```

So whats going on here. The page stops working when I use this line,  `$diff=$diff->format("%i minutes");`

I was under the impression I had to format the date from the database by using, `$order_start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', $order_start);`.

$order_start echo's `2017-07-31 01:44:25`

$now_date echo's `2017-07-31 04:43:59`

Which looks like the same format but may not be?

Now I'm trying to get the difference between these times and format the result to show minutes.

Thanks for the advice in advance! If there is a better article on here let me know.

I tried
[Echo Difference in Two Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473603/echo-difference-in-two-times)

I also read this to try and figure out the formatting.
http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

[My Order page](https://www.aarontomlinson.com/driverorders.php)

Comment: `date_diff` function will accept bot parameter as object of `DateTime` but in your code `$now_date` is string also dont know what `$order_time` have?

Comment: the $order_time comes out of the database where it was stored as a datetime with this format. 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

You may convert your dates into `timestamp` and get the difference, then format it accordingly. Use like this

```
echo date('H:i:s',(strtotime($now_date)-strtotime($order_start)));
```

in your case use like this

```
echo date('h:i:s',(strtotime("2017-07-31 01:44:25")-strtotime("2017-07-31 04:43:59")));
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. I thought after I formatted the times that I wouldnt need strtotime for some reason.

Comment: To be on the safe side. I actually had to adjust your answer to `<? echo date('H:i:s',($order_start-strtotime($now_date))); ?>`. However, the strtotime was the correct problem.

Comment: actually it just doesn't work, times are wrong just about every way I twist it. using your answer I got 19:59:34 instead of 3:59:34,  and when the time should be zero its 16:00:00.

Comment: I used a lowercase h for the date format and it turned 16:00:00 into 4:00:00 which is closer? I also started my page with `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` so I don't think its a timezone issue.

Comment: i upadated my answer, it giving me the exact difference

Comment: I don't think your edit is the solution.    I am comparing our current time to the time an order was placed on my website and stored to the database.   All the orders will have a different timestamps. Your solution works for only one instance.